# How to use rasa CollectionDispather to send video as response?

Tags: chatbot, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x, rasa-sdk

I tried below code blocks to show videos :

```
dispatcher.utter_message(attachment = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/-F6h43DRpcU")
dispatcher.utter_message(video = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/-F6h43DRpcU")
dispatcher.utter_attachment(attachment = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/-F6h43DRpcU")
```

```
dispatcher.utter_attachment(attachment={
              "type": "video",
              "payload": {
                  "title": "Watch Below Video",
                  "src": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/-F6h43DRpcU"
              }
            })
```

but none of these worked.

what is correct format to get video as a response in rasa chat?

Comment: which UI/widget you are using?

Comment: I am using rocketchat

Comment: As you are using third party UI for rasa, it is completely depends on the UI how they are rendering the response. however, you can follow this link for reference https://forum.rasa.com/t/displaying-video-in-the-rasa-webchat/26931 
You also need to check what all response types are accepted by your frontend. If any response type is not supported by your frontend, please ask them to implement the feature.